Can my plane get off the ground?
I'm building a ultralight aircraft. I have a Rotax 447 that produces 40 horsepower and 175 pounds of thrust. The plane is going to have a wingspan of 20 feet by 5 feet and the max takeoff weight of my plane will be 400 pounds including me. It produces 480 pounds of lift including the drag. Mind you I will get professional advice but this is just some advice. Can it get off the ground? What propeller should I use?

What do you mean it produces 480 lbs of lift? At what airspeed/angle of attack?

480 pounds of lift at 24 knots (the maximum stall speed) and 10 degrees

If you don't know what prop you're using, how do you know the thrust this might produce?

That's just the most efficient way it will probably be a smaller amount

Just look at similar design to have an idea: the Pterodactyl has more or less the same weight and needs only 16hp

Ok thanks! I'll look into it

No, you should assume that your craft will not leave the ground.
Not because of any specific performance value, but because you're building from scratch an aircraft that can very easily kill you if even one out of a whole host of details isn't correct, and you're asking an Internet forum questions like "what propeller should I use" and "can this get off the ground?"
Until you have a design that was drafted by a professional, with all such questions answered well before the first step of construction starts, you absolutely should not plan to entrust your life to this craft and any answers you get here.
The level of assurance that "I think this might work" is fine for foam and balsa wood gliders, but you need far more certainty than that before any person goes flying, or attempts to, in such a craft.  The early history of aviation has plenty of examples of craft that flew, barely, just high enough to produce a fatal crash when something went wrong.
Planning to be flying at your stall speed isn't a very good plan; until you know (with far better assurance than random people on the internet can provide) that your craft can fly with adequate margin above stall speed, at reasonable bank angles, while climbing or encountering gusts, you have no business allowing anybody, including yourself, to take it flying.
No, this should never get off the ground!

I'm not going to be flying at stall speed that's just the speed I need to get off the ground and I'm using sticka spruce and I'm going to get it checked by the faa
